Need to display image captions at the bottom of the viewport, not bottom of page
I need the captions of each image to be centred at the bottom of the viewport, so that when the user scrolls, the captions are always in the same place (on hover).
Apologies if this is incorrectly laid out, I'm very new to code.
I was unable to link the actual images I used as it was marked by spam here.. so it's not showing the layout as I'd wish.


.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* Ensure .gallery is positioned */
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.caption {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Ensure captions appear in front of images */
}

.image-container:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 1" src="1.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="2.jpg" src="2.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 3" src="3.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 4" src="4.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 5" src="5.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 6" src="6.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 7" src="7.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 8" src="8.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 9" src="9.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 10" src="10.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 11" src="11.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 12" src="12.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 12</div>
  </div>
</div>



Tried many options, some resulting in the captions being bottom centre of each image, but never the bottom of the viewport as wished.

Made a snippet and corrected the missing opening div for 'caption4'. Your code seems to be working properly in snippet. You are using position: fixed.

@Mehdi thank you so much!! Honestly can't explained how much I appreciate your help. Thank you thank you thank you

@Mehdi Weirdly, when I added the code to Cargo (site building platform), it didn't work as like the snippet you created. The text still remains at the very bottom of the page - no clue why.. Don't suppose you have any ideas? Thanks again !

yes that s strange. Actualy don't have this with chrome or edge when trying stays at position fixed 20px from bottom of the window (not document)

Suggest you NOT do <br> <br> <br> but instead put CSS for .gallery {margin-top: 3em;}

First is pretty much what you have but perhaps with less CSS.  I did center the alternate text in the image space and used a margin not <br><br><br> at the top.  I used em as easier for my brain to work with and better match the <br> there.
Borders just show what is where for this example code.


body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
}

.image-container {
  border: solid 1px #FF0000;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: solid 1px #0000FF;
  text-align: center;
}

.caption {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  left: 50%;
}

.caption {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.625em;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

.image-container:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
}
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 1" src="1.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="2.jpg" src="2.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 3" src="3.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 4" src="4.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 5" src="5.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 6" src="6.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 7" src="7.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 8" src="8.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 9" src="9.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 10" src="10.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 11" src="11.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Placeholder Image 12" src="12.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 12</div>
  </div>
</div>



Less is more perhaps?  Remove the wrappers and put it all in a grid with the captions in the last row.  Does need a fixed row count.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 3em;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto) [last-line];
  grid-gap: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery>img {
  height: auto;
  border: solid 1px #0000FF;
  text-align: center;
}

img:hover+.caption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.caption {
  background-color: #000000B2;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.625em;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
  grid-row: last-line;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
}
<div class="gallery">
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 1" src="1.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 1</div>
  <img alt="2.jpg" src="2.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 2</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 3" src="3.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 3</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 4" src="4.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 4</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 5" src="5.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 5</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 6" src="6.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 6</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 7" src="7.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 7</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 8" src="8.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 8</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 9" src="9.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 9</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 10" src="10.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 10</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 11" src="11.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 11</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 12" src="12.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 12</div>
</div>



Slightly different twist on this to remove all the wrappers then place all the captions in the last grid row; then move the row up with a negative margin.  Not exactly what you asked for here really so I hide it by default.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 3em;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto) [last-line];
  grid-gap: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery>img {
  height: auto;
  border: solid 1px #0000FF;
  text-align: center;
}

img:hover+.caption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.caption {
  background-color: #000000B2;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.625em;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
  grid-row: last-line;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
<div class="gallery">
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 1" src="1.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 1</div>
  <img alt="2.jpg" src="2.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 2</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 3" src="3.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 3</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 4" src="4.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 4</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 5" src="5.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 5</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 6" src="6.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 6</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 7" src="7.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 7</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 8" src="8.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 8</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 9" src="9.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 9</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 10" src="10.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 10</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 11" src="11.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 11</div>
  <img alt="Placeholder Image 12" src="12.jpg">
  <div class="caption">Caption for Image 12</div>
</div>



